# Sum of digits buffer overflow

Tags: c, buffer, buffer-overflow

I am a new in programming in C and I am looking for solution for specific problem. I have to create a program to sum digits. What I did it's not perfect, but the code works until the string is not too long like 10000 digits in stdin and I get stuck with this. I can't put all these numbers, because I get overflow. I guess, I should create some kind of buffer, but I don't know how to do it from stdin. Thank you for any Ideas. ( I'm Sorry about my English, it is not perfect)

```
#include <math.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>

int main()  {


long a; 
long value;
long c;

char s[10000];

printf("Input an integer\n");
scanf("%s", s);

value = a = 0; 

while (s[a] != '\0') {
c   = s[a] - '0'; 
value = value + c;
a++; }


          if(value < 10){
          printf("Sum of digits %ld\n", value);} 


                             while(value >= 10){
                             long  digit = 0;
                             long  value2 = 0;

                             while (value > 0)
                             {
                             digit = value % 10;
                             value2  = value2 + digit;
                             value /= 10;}

 printf("Sum of digits %ld \n",value2);  }

 return 0; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a buffer because you can calculate the sum on the fly:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>  // EXIT_FAILURE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>   // isdigit()

int main()
{
    puts("Input an integer:");

    long long unsigned sum = 0;
    for (int ch = fgetc(stdin); ch != EOF && ch != '\n'; ch = fgetc(stdin)) {
        if (isdigit(ch)) {
            sum += (ch - '0');
        }
        else {
            fprintf(stderr, "'%c' is not a valid digit :(\n\n", ch);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    printf("Sum of digits: %llu\n\n", sum);
}
```

Comment: I have just one additional question I put  int variable "counter" inside a for loop because when I put like 6000 digits the result seems incorrect and it always shows 4095 cycles why is that ?

Comment: @JustBeginner what sum are you expecting and does that fit within a long long unsigned on your platform?

Comment: The sum of digits is correct until the string  it is not too long

Comment: @JustBeginner You can overcome that limitation by using a bigger type for `sum`.

Comment: Isn't the long long unsigned the biggest?

Comment: @JustBeginner [List of arbitrary-precision arithmetic software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software), or you can also implement your own solution as an exercise.

Comment: I actually created a new version yesterday, I was little bit curious and the numbers are now loaded from one file and it works perfectly, but it is not a stdin. It just open file take some char  and compare it with ascii value 47-58 range.